# Sound on Power-On

Tags: audio, custom-roms, device-firmware, kernel, power-on

I want a sound to be played when the user presses the power button, Since I am customizing Android for Visually Challenged people this feature might let them know if the tablet has actually powered on or not.

This feature is by default switched off in my firmware. And also I think that since this sound comes just when the device is switched on, that is, before the Android Boots, the power on sound should be a function of underlying Linux kernel.

Any clue how to go about it and turn it on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you describe it as "underlying kernel functionality", it is rather a development question (and thus would be off topic here). Initially you however describe you want the sound being played whenever the power button is pressed; things like that are usually doable using *Tasker*. However, when pressing the power button usually the screen reacts (switching either on or off); if a user cannot see that, I'm a bit at a loss regarding how (s)he shall use the device at all?

Comment: @Izzy: I'm a bit at a loss regarding how (s)he shall use the device at all? 
That is handled by some customized TTS and gestures enabled launcher.
Anyways I have no clue about the Tasker..let me look into it.

Comment: Two links for you: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (Playstore) and my personal [Tasker ressources listing](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/). The latter is mostly German, but you'll figure the links and headlines (plenty of English stuff in there as well). And right, there was "haptic feedback" and TTS. Just hard to imagine if one's not affected... I could write up an answer with some useful Tasker examples (TTS, haptics, voice-control) if that would help you, just let me know.

Comment: @Izzy: I couldn't relate to what link I should look into even after translating the page into English. Anyways I don't want to install some app (and that too paid..:P); I want to know some code level details as to where I can turn some boolean from false to true to play the sound on power button press or just rectify the path to the power_on.ogg. or something along those lines.

Comment: First, there's a free 7-day trial on the [Tasker homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). Second: for "code level details", this is the wrong place -- for that you'd rather check with our brothers and sisters at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). However, my offer stands if you count it as a possible solution: I can compile an answer with useful automation for your case, such as specific feedback, voice control, and the like.

Comment: One of the brothers and sister from stack overflow suggested me that these question are not related to android development and should not be posted there..hence I [deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427369/compile-jellybean-keyboard-in-ics-rom?noredirect=1#comment21818278_15427369) my question from stack overflow..:X
Anyways where should I go for Firmware question or that brother was not correct??

Comment: As I wrote: We deal with problems on the *user-end* here -- and development stuff ("code level details") is off-topic (see our [FAQ]). You might, however, want to check with [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a good place, if SO doesn't accept the topic either. I'd say the [XDA community](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) should be a good place.